# Posts won't be deleted from database

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite, sql-delete

In my application I'm using SQLite3, and right now I'm trying to get DELETE to work. The code below seems fine for me, and I've checked that $producerId holds the Id, which of course exists in the database.

However, I get false back as a result from the query execution, and the posts doesn't get deleted.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public function deleteProducer($producerId) {

    $sql = "DELETE FROM 'producers' WHERE 'producerid' = $producerId";

    $result = $this->m_db->exec($sql);

    return $result;  // <- 0 (fails)
}
```

**database structure:**

```
Table: producers
Fields: id(INTEGER PRIMARY KEY), producerid(INT), name(TEXT), address(TEXT), zipcode(INT), town(TEXT), url(TEXT), imgurl(TEXT)
```

Comment: I think the issue is here `DELETE FROM 'producers'` don't you use backticks **`** to specify a table or column? I haven't used sqlite myself so I could be way off the mark

Comment: why dont you try `DELETE FROM producers WHERE producerid = $producerId` instead of what you are trying. **No Quotes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, single quotes are used for strings.

SQLite will accept a string instead of an identifer when the meaning is clear from the context (such as for the table name), but in the `WHERE` condition, strings *are* allowed, so `'producerid'` will be interpreted as string.

For identifiers, use double quotes:

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM "producers" WHERE "producerid" = $producerId';
```